# How can I search Domain Integrated DNS Entries

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, internal-dns

Example:

1. I have a server named server1.domain.local
2. I have lots of CNAME entries in various forward lookup zones pointed to server1.domain.local
3. I want to decomission server1, and have a new server, server2, that is going to replace it.

I need to change all of my CNAMEs that point to server1.domain.local to point to server2.domain.local.

I know I can create server1.domain.local as another CNAME, but I would prefer to just find all the entries and change them individually.

How can I go about finding all references in all forward lookup zones to server.domain.local?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dnscmd` utility from the Windows Support Tools is probably your best bet. You can get a list of all the DNS zones with the command: `dnscmd [servername] /EnumZones`. You can enumerate all the CNAME records in each zone with the command: `dnscmd [servername] /EnumRecords [zone name] . /TYPE CNAME`.

In theory you could chain these two together in a script, process the output, and make the changes you want automatically (also using `dnscmd` with the `/RecordDelete` and `/RecordAdd` commands). That's an exercise I'll leave to you (for now).

Edit: Okay-- I couldn't resist. Here's that script. It will only `echo` the commands that actually make changes. If it does what you want then you can pull the `echo` commands out and let 'er rip.

```
@echo off

set SERVER_TO_REPLACE=server1.domain.com
set REPLACEMENT_VALUE=server2.domain.com

rem Quick and dirty list of Primary zones that aren't Reverse zones
for /F "usebackq" %%i in (`dnscmd %1 /EnumZones ^| find " Primary" ^| find /v " Rev"`) do call :process_zone %1 %%i
goto end

:process_zone
rem Quick and dirty enumeration of all CNAME records in a zone
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,3,4" %%i in (`dnscmd %1 /EnumRecords %2 . /TYPE CNAME ^| find " CNAME"`) do call :process_RR %1 %2 %%i %%j %%k
goto end

:process_RR
rem Check a record and alter it if necessary
if /I "%5" EQU "%SERVER_TO_REPLACE%" (
  echo dnscmd %1 /RecordDelete %2 %3 %4 %5 /f
  echo dnscmd %1 /RecordAdd %2 %3 %4 %REPLACEMENT_VALUE%
)

:end
```

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to run `nslookup` from one of your DNS servers, or a system that is permitted to perform a zone transfer.  With `nslookup` do a `ls > file` which will request a copy of the zone database and save it to a text file.  Then the search feature in your favorite text editor to find things to fix.

Comment: Bear in mind that, by default, a Windows DNS server won't permit zone transfers. The OP would need to allow zone transfers in order to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Are these AD integrated zones? If not, you can manually edit the zone files with notepad (find and replace) and then reload the zones.

***EDIT***

My bad. I didn't see in your title that these are AD integrated zones. You can still use the method I posted by changing the zones to non-AD integrated zones, editing the zone files that will be created, then changing them back to AD integrated zones. It's a bit of a hack so this may not be the method you'd prefer to use.