# How do I search Microsoft DNS?

Tags: windows-dns

I'm about to switch a mail server. I'd like to be able to search Microsoft DNS where

> MX Server == 'mail.foo.com'

Or, perhaps

> CNAME.name == 'mail' OR CNAME.value == 'mail.foo.com'

Does anyone know of a tool that will permit to accomplish something like this?

Comment: It is very hard to understand what it is you're asking. My instinct says you're looking for something like `nslookup -type=MX mail.foo.com`

Comment: No. I have a Microsoft DNS server, it has 150,000 domains. I want to find domains that have the MX server already set to mail.foo.com so I know what the change I want to make will effect.

Comment: Anything wrong with a perl / python / ruby / whatever script that looks up the MX record for all 150,000 domains? That's the simplest method as far as human time is concerned.

Comment: How would I get the list of domains the DNS server provides, in the end grepping through the folder as mentioned in my answer was by far the best solution for me.

Comment: If you don't know the list of domain you're authoritative for, then yes I'd get grepping.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

1. Install [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html).
2. Browse to `C:\Windows\System32\dns`
3. Use `grep`.

Like any Microsoft Problem, it's most easily solved with the Cygwin port of the Linux toolset.

Comment: FYI, Windows has a built-in "find" command to... well... find text inside files. Or you can use PowerShell to do even better searching.

Comment: This is a terrible solution as you can easily solve it in Powershell, and as such it doesn't really deserve to be accepted.

Comment: This folder doesn't seem to contain the complete set of DNS entries served by my server anyway (2012 R2). It's mostly just a log file.

Answer (score 19):

Here are a few ideas:

- If you're using zone files to store the zones (i.e. not Active Directory integrated zones) then you can just use `find`, `findstr`, or your favorite `grep` port to search the zone files (stored in `%SystemRoot%\system32\dns` by default).
- You could use `nslookup` or `dig` and perform queries against the DNS server
- You can use the command-line `dnscmd` tool to dump zones and search them with `find`, `findstr`, `grep`, etc.
- You could sort the columns in the DNS management console snap-in to cause the data you're looking for to appear in a known location

I'm not exactly sure I understand what you're looking for, but I'd lean toward the first two ideas as being the best ways. I do find myself, from time to time, sorting the columns in the DNS management console to quickly see if I've created a given record.

Edit:

150,000 domains. Zow.

You could probably hack the script [in this answer I wrote](https://serverfault.com/a/270672/7200) to loop thru your zones looking for the records you want. It shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Where do I get `dnscmd`, for Windows Server 2008?

Comment: It's part of the Windows Support Tools. They're in the "SUPPORT\TOOLS" folder on the installation media.

Comment: gha. I don't have the installation media it's on a cloud server.

Comment: Download an evaluation version of Windows Server 2008 R2, if nothing else.

Comment: That sounds way more complex than just grepping the directory with all of the files in it.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: If the zones are stored in files then grepping them is fine. Active Directory integrated zones won't be stored in files.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so this is probably going off the reservation as far as the "official method" but this is what I've always done. As long as the zone files are being stored on disk (external domains, not AD), you can use the following Powershell script to search the text zone files for specific IP addresses/host names/record types.

```
Param ([String]$searchPattern)

      $resultsFormat = @{Expression={$_.Filename};Label="File"},
                       @{Expression={$_.LineNumber};Label="Line"},
                       @{Expression={$_.Line};Label="Text"}

      $searchResults = Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.dns" | Select-String -Pattern $searchPattern | ft $resultsFormat -AutoSize

If ($searchResults) {$searchResults} Else {Write-Host "`nNo search results`n"}
```

Save this script to the "C:\Windows\System32\DNS" folder and name it "query.ps1". Then run it from Powershell by changing to that directory and typing "query.ps1 ".

I share this folder on all my DNS servers (for admins only) and then map a drive to it. This way I can run the script from my workstation by executing it from the mapped drive. Easy Peasy.

Examples:

Find all the DNS entries with "192.168.1.1" in them

```
.\query.ps1 192.168.1.1
```

Find all the DNS entries with "www" in them

```
.\query.ps1 www
```

Find all the DNS entries with "mx" in them

```
.\query.ps1 mx
```

Answer (score 1):

nslookup

```
    set type=mx
    domain.com
```

when you press enter, the dns will resolve all the mail type records regarding that specific domain.

Comment: but, I want to query the local DNS server for where the mail record equals something -- I do not want to dump the MX record for a single domain.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for DNS entries in the GUI, where you would expect to search, if using the GUI to create entries is not possible because, surprisingly, Microsoft did not include in the DNS GUI which is why you need to revert to using a command or script.

Comment: A more specific answer may be helpful, otherwise you might consider leaving a comment instead.